# IntelliJ 13 autocompletion

Tags: autocomplete, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 13 on MacOSX and seeing a strange thing. Previously, I did not have problems with the classes being autocompleted, but I have now seen strange classes imported.

We recently moved from JUnit to TestNG testing, and I have a habit of prefixing my Assert statements with the (last part of the) package. So `assertEquals` would be `Assert.assertEquals`.

I have always done this and previously IntelliJ did not make suggestions when I get to the `.`

I have the correct `Assert` class imported in the code `import org.testng.Assert;`, however, now when I type `Assert.` as soon as I type the `.`, the Assert is replaced with `org.junit.Assert.`

Does anyone know of a way to force IntelliJ to use the imported class first in the autocompletion list?

Comment: Do you also have junit on the classpath?

Comment: Yes, but that's beside the point. The 'Assert' from the correct package/library is already imported at the start of the class. I just want the imported one used (IntelliJ _not_ to qualify the name).

Comment: That sounds like a defect. You should consider reporting it to Jetbrains.